# Rails - How do I limit user-generated create actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, the user can create up to two aliases. I know how to build a check into the html which will disable the option to create another alias if they already have two. However, how do I build this limit into the model?

Edit: I understand I can put a condition on the form, but I want to put the condition into my controller. That's what I want to figure out.

Comment: U need to show an error message or disable the the create form entirely after the condition match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **alias Model**, add custom validation to count the number of aliases for the current user:

```
validate :more_than_two_for_user

def more_than_two_for_user
  if self.class.where(:user_id => user_id).where('id != ?', id).count > 1 
    errors.add(:base,'too many aliases')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `count`. If count of user's groups is greater or equal to 2, prevent the creation of the new one.